# How to evaluate Application Insights requests "own" duration, without considering duration of dependencies?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to produce a Kusto query to measure the "own" duration of the requests (subtracting out durations of dependencies). However, I can't really figure out how to work this out through a pure Kusto query.

To better understand what would would expected, below a sample case:

**High level view (where R is the request and Dx the dependencies)**

```
 R    =============================== (31ms)
 D1     ******* (7ms)
 D2          ******** (8ms)
 D3                        ****** (6ms)
 D4                          ** (2ms)
 D5         **** (4ms)

 Proj ==*************======******====
```

- `D1` overlaps `D2` during 2ms
- `D5` and `D4` shouldn't be taken into account as completely overlapped by other dependencies
- `Proj` being a projection of a *potential* intermediate step where only meaningful dependencies segments are shown

Given the following testbed dataset

```
let reqs = datatable (timestamp: datetime, id:string, duration: real)
[
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.000Z"), "r1", 31    // R
];
let deps = datatable (timestamp: datetime, operation_ParentId:string, duration: real)
[
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.002Z"), "r1", 7,    // D1
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.007Z"), "r1", 8,    // D2
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.021Z"), "r1", 6,    // D3
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.023Z"), "r1", 2,    // D4
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.006Z"), "r1", 4,    // D5
];
```

In this particular case, the Kusto query, joining the two data tables, should be able to retrieve `12` (duration of the request, removing all dependencies), ie.

```
Expected total duration = 31 - (7 + 8 - 2) - (6) = 12
```

Any help to move this forward would be greatly appreciated <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded to solve that using that using [`row_window_session()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/row-window-session-function). This is a Window function. You can read more about it at [Window functions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/windowsfunctions).

The solution is:

```
let reqs = datatable (timestamp: datetime, operation_ParentId:string, duration: real)
[
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.000Z"), "r1", 31    // R
];
let deps = datatable (timestamp: datetime, operation_ParentId:string, duration: real)
[
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.002Z"), "r1", 7,    // D1
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.007Z"), "r1", 8,    // D2
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.021Z"), "r1", 6,    // D3
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.006Z"), "r1", 4,    // D5
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.023Z"), "r1", 2,    // D4
];
deps
| extend endTime = timestamp + totimespan(duration * 10000)
| sort by timestamp asc 
| serialize | extend SessionStarted = row_window_session(timestamp, 1h, 1h, timestamp > prev(endTime))
| summarize max(endTime) by operation_ParentId, SessionStarted
| extend diff = max_endTime - SessionStarted
| summarize todouble(sum(diff)) by operation_ParentId
| join reqs on operation_ParentId
| extend diff = duration - sum_diff / 10000
| project diff
```

The idea here is to sort the entries by the open time, and as long as the next previous end time is later than the current start time, we don't open a new session. Let's explain each line of this query to see how this is being done:

1. Calculate the `endTime` based on the duration. To normalize the data I'll multiply by 10000 the duration:

   ```
   | extend endTime = timestamp + totimespan(duration * 10000)
   ```
2. Sort by start time:

   ```
   | sort by timestamp asc
   ```
3. This is the key of this solution. It is calculated on the `timestamp` column. The next two parameters are limits when to start new buckets. Since we don't want to seal a bucket based on time that have passed, I provided 1 hour which will not hit with this input. The forth argument helps us to create a new session based on the data. As long as there are more rows that will result in `timestamp > prev(endTime)` they will have the same start time.

   ```
   | serialize | extend SessionStarted = row_window_session(timestamp, 1h, 1h, timestamp > prev(endTime))
   ```
4. Now we have multiple rows per session start. So we want to keep only the latest time per session. We also keep `operation_ParentId` to later on join on that key:

   ```
   | summarize max(endTime) by operation_ParentId, SessionStarted
   ```
5. Calculate the time of each session:

   ```
   | extend diff = max_endTime - SessionStarted
   ```
6. Sum up all session times:

   ```
   | summarize todouble(sum(diff)) by operation_ParentId
   ```
7. Join on `req` to get the total starting time:

   ```
   | join reqs on operation_ParentId
   ```
8. Calculate the diff between the total time and the session times. Unnormalize the data:

   ```
   | extend diff = duration - sum_diff / 10000
   ```
9. Project the final result:

   ```
   | project diff
   ```

You can find this query running at [Kusto Samples open database](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8WTTVODMBCG7/yKnZ5AwQb6OTh68uLNsT3pOExsUk0HCCaprY4/3g20Aa2OvQlkmGT32fdlE3JuQPEXDRfAqMH7MefgG1FwbWhRpXaV22kIsuKKGiHL7IYqXpprlmqjRPkUAls3kRRr0Tzw7j1woN9LSEKiOIni0ZxMU0LwOSOE3PWCEHoq7oUwiAGvfh9uvYdzL0dPjFf/4CnpeJqEO09X8RHkpENOHZn8TSZxhxw7cnCE5rhDDh05OkJz0CETRw5t823jvQ/gW8NLBjjmWAd3wrUfTsHIelbR0t93GU4gxj0lAbJaKgOPbx2E6gXYAFeC5uKdgxOYca0RnxmqDGeoo%20Qm24iS4Us3sXbnQ4ifm9GWvoRK8Vd/ZzSo9ddFQZWVKejWRayjw%20MSfnPQfjoTyyX6wRLZvgvRYXKrZSSTazypPi75Fg5%20kURqJUXZ/HbYuR8zvppwXY6sYFav9puGY26l5IovTJ38CYAlPbnQAwAA).

Having said that, please note that this is a linear operation. Meaning that if there are 2 following segments, that should be under the same segment, but they do not intersect, it will fail. For example, adding the following into `deps`:

```
datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.026Z"), "r1", 1,    // D6
```

which should not add anything to the calculation, cause it to misbehave. This is because `d4` is the previous point, and it has no point of contact with `d6`, although `d3` covers them both.
To solve that, you need to repeat the same logic of steps 3-5. Unfortunately Kusto does not have recursions, therefore you cannot solve this for any kind of input. But assuming there are no really depth such cases that breaks this logic, I think it is good enough.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for this great answer and the very articulated explanation! <3

Comment: Sure @nulltoken :) I formerly worked as a developer in Kusto. It's a great project. Thanks a lot for the bounty!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the query below to see if it can meet your requirement:

```
let reqs = datatable (timestamp: datetime, id:string, duration: real, key1:string)
[
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.000Z"), "r1", 31 , "k1"   // R
];

let deps = datatable (timestamp: datetime, operation_ParentId:string, duration: real,name:string)
[
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.002Z"), "r1", 7, "D1", 
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.007Z"), "r1", 8, "D2", 
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.021Z"), "r1", 6, "D3", 
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.023Z"), "r1", 2, "D4", 
  datetime("2020-12-15T08:00:00.006Z"), "r1", 4, "D5"
];

let d2 = deps
| where name !in ("D4","D5")
| summarize a=sum(duration)-2
| extend key1="k1";

reqs 
| join d2 on key1
| extend result = duration - a
| project result
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. However, the question was about how to "measure the "own" duration of the requests (substracting out durations of dependencies)" in general, not how to solve _this_ particular example. Updating the question to make the intent more clear.