# KQL, time difference between separate rows in same table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have `Sessions` table

```
Sessions
|Timespan|Name |No|
|12:00:00|Start|1 |
|12:01:00|End  |2 |
|12:02:00|Start|3 |
|12:04:00|Start|4 |
|12:04:30|Error|5 |
```

I need to extract from it duration of each session using KQL (but if you could give me suggestion how I can do it with some other query language it would be also very helpful). But if next row after `start` is also `start`, it means session was abandoned and we should ignore it.

Expected result:

```
|Duration|SessionNo|
|00:01:00|    1    |
|00:00:30|    4    |
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65646154/2359227) is similar, yet different, question that you might want to take a look at.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Sessions
| order by No asc 
| extend nextName = next(Name), nextTimestamp = next(timestamp)
| where Name == "Start" and nextName != "Start"
| project Duration = nextTimestamp - timestamp, No
```

When using the operator `order by`, you are getting a [Serialized row set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/windowsfunctions#serialized-row-set), which then you can use operators such as [`next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/nextfunction) and [`prev`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/prevfunction). Basically you are seeking rows with `No == "Start"` and `next(Name) == "End"`, so this is what I did,

You can find this query running at [Kusto Samples open database](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02OQQ6CUAxE955iZAUJHoEdazZwgQpNwOT/T9oSNfHwVgR01cm08zotq04p6umFJAMLrk80CaQ93OKHcRwQfTYUGNUq848uylV3U2A1CvO+s90oPH8fWRjfaIWsNRLLQP/I8+H7/Szpxr2hXoTMa23Q35MLDn7pPd8iaXz7vgAAAA==).

Comment: Note that `serialize` should not be used here, and `order by` should be used instead, since Kusto does not guarantee any order for the records, and in your case, order is important, should you should explicitly tell Kusto what order you want.

Comment: @SlavikN, theoretically speaking you are right. Technically speaking, when the data set is so small, and it is on the same extent, I am pretty sure the order is preserved. But yes, when the data is large, and you have many extents, the data is not preserved and then you should use `order by` which returns, by thy way, a serialized result, as it is shows in the docs as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/serializeoperator#example

Comment: You shouldn't make any assumptions on the amount of extents, as Kusto can split/merge extents in the background according to what it sees fit, and according to various policies. So even when the amount of records is small (which wasn't stated as an assumption in the posted question, by the way), it doesn't necessarily mean there's just one extent.

Comment: @SlavikN, although I don't think you can find a real example of reorder lines of the the code: `let Sessions = datatable [ ... ]`, I will update my answer for the sake of those that are going to find this answer and run it on real data, where as I agreed before there the order is not preserved.

Answer (score 3):

```
let Sessions = datatable(Timestamp: datetime, Name: string, No: long) [
    datetime(12:00:00),"Start",1,
    datetime(12:01:00),"End",2,
    datetime(12:02:00),"Start",3,
    datetime(12:04:00),"Start",4,
    datetime(12:04:30),"Error",5
];
Sessions
| order by No asc
| extend Duration = iff(Name != "Start" and prev(Name) == "Start", Timestamp - prev(Timestamp), timespan(null)), SessionNo = prev(No)
| where isnotnull(Duration)
| project Duration, SessionNo
```

Comment: Tested this one and it also works nicely. In case we have 1 more column ```userId``` and different users can start independent sessions, just changing ```| order by No asc``` to ```| order by userId,No asc``` allows to still get what I wanted with your query. Thanks!